# BlackBerry OAuth Alternative

Tags: java, blackberry, oauth

I am starting to think that there are no OAuth libraries that I can use with BlackBerry mobile devices. The only possibility I have found is the following, which I have yet to look into with detail:

http://github.com/fireeagle/j2me-oauth

So, my question is (assuming there are no other libraries), what is a work around for this? Would it be possible to have my application use an embedded browser, and do the authentication via javascript or php or something like that, and then find a way to pass the authenticated token to my application? I want my app to be a native Java application on the BlackBerry, I don't want it to turn into a complete web application that just displays in an embedded browser. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look into

[signpost](http://github.com/kaeppler/signpost) and [signpost old site](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)

Or this one

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~brightkitemobile-dev/brightkitemobile/trunk/files/head%3A/trunk/src/com/orangatame/mobile/oauth/